# Google Apps Script ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use TextEncoder in Apps Script:

```
const textEncoder = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
let str = "test";
alert(textEncoder.encode(str));
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

I guess it's not supported by Apps Script. Is there a way to use TextEncoder in Apps Script (maybe I'm missing a reference), or a 'long way' of doing the code above using other JS or Apps Script commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following Javascript to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    const textEncoder = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
    let str = "test";
    alert(textEncoder.encode(str));
  ```

  - When this script is run, `116,101,115,116` is returned.

Unfortunately, at Google Apps Script, `new TextEncoder` cannot be used. So, in this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const str = "test";
  const res = Utilities.newBlob(str).getBytes();
  console.log(res) // [ 116, 101, 115, 116 ]
}
```

- At Google Apps Script, UTF-8 is used as the default.
- When this script is run, you can see the value of `[ 116, 101, 115, 116 ]` at the log.
- In the case of `const res = Utilities.newBlob(str).getBytes()`, the array of twos-complement 8-bit signed integers is returned. This is for Google Apps Script.
- If you want to retrieve the array of 8-bit unsigned integers, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const res = Utilities.newBlob(str).getBytes();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const res = [...Uint8Array.from(Utilities.newBlob(str).getBytes())];
    ```

#### References:

- [newBlob(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata_1)
- [getBytes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getbytes)